# Issue with simple inflate to linear layout in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff00ff"
    android:id="@+id/candyBox">
</LinearLayout>
```

and i want to populate the above to the columns 1,2,3,4 layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >
    <!-- 4 LAYERS of linear layout, ready to be inflated -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/column1"
        android:gravity="bottom">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/column2">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/column3">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/column4">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am doing this simple code:

```
 LinearLayout column1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.column1);
    View viewToLoad = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.candy_box, null);
    column1.addView(viewToLoad);
```

And nothing seems to happen, is there any problem with my code? seems straightforward. If i hard code the thing, all is well, but i need those dynamically inserted, there is a "Java" way, and there is this... i need to do it like that, i don't see how it's a problem with the sum.

For it to be more clearer, my end result should be like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:id="@+id/column1"
    android:gravity="bottom">
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff00ff"
        android:id="@+id/candyBox">
    </LinearLayout>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check if there is any exception.

Comment: No exception, i'm updating to my full code in just a moment

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the weight of your outer layout - weightSum  should be in the outer and layout_weight in the inner layout.
To make sure that what you are doing is right, I also suggest to hard code the inner layout inside and look at the layout in the graphical design page in the IDE.

**Update 2:** I what you want should be something like this:

[image: Android studio layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="4"
              android:background="#44000000"
    >
    <!-- 4 LAYERS of linear layout, ready to be inflated -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/column1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#33ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:id="@+id/candyBox1">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:id="@+id/candyBox2">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/column2"
        android:background="#22ffffff"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:id="@+id/candyBox3">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/column3">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/column4">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The `weightSum` should account for that

Comment: Exactly, the weightSum is 5, and i want to add the one with the 1 to the father. if i hardcode it all is well, can't see the problem there

Comment: weightSum should go in the outer view.

Comment: The opposite! doron, i want the candy to be in the inner of column 1, please see the update

Answer (score 1):

Why are you defining `android:layout_weight="1"` when your **LinearLayout** seems to be your rootView element?

***UPDATE***

Looks like you inverted some stuff. You should be finding by id **candy_box** and setting **column1** programmatically.

Try this.

```
LinearLayout candyBoxLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.candy_box);
View viewToLoad = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.column1, null);

candyBoxLayout.addView(viewToLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the structure of the xml:

my layouts were not in the root object so i had to do the following which works:

```
     column1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.column1);
     View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.candy_box,column1 ,false);
     column1.addView(v);
```

The false is the key, which says it is not the root element.

SOLVED!